# Sql Update Query for updating range of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im looking for a way to Update some table row base on condition

my old query is like :

```
update Database1.dbo.Table1 
set Database1.dbo.Table1.AllVisit = (select COUNT(ID) from Database1.dbo.Table2 WHERE UserID = Database1.dbo.Table1.UserID group by UserID)
```

now i want to update only last day fileds of table1 instead all of theme 
is this query ok to work with ?

```
    update Database1.dbo.Table1 
    set Database1.dbo.Table1.AllVisit = (select COUNT(ID) from Database1.dbo.Table2 WHERE UserID = Database1.dbo.Table1.UserID And UserDate between
DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))  and  convert(date, GETDATE()) group by UserID)
```

or this one :

```
update Database1.dbo.Table1 
    set Database1.dbo.Table1.AllVisit = (select COUNT(ID) from Database1.dbo.Table2 WHERE UserID = Database1.dbo.Table1.UserID And UserDate between
DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))  and  convert(date, GETDATE()) group by UserID) Where
Database1.dbo.Table1.UserDate between
DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))  and  convert(date, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Do you want update only previous day's table1 rows with previous day's data form table2?

Comment: @HardCoreProgrammer Exactly that's what im up to.
im using this query to update only last day row of table1  with last day visit row on table2.
other record must be unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
update A
set A.AllVisit = (select COUNT(ID) 
                    from Database1.dbo.Table2 
                    WHERE UserID = A.UserID 
                          And convert(varchar(100),UserDate,101) = convert(varchar(100),getdate()-1,101)
                    )
FROM  Database1.dbo.Table1 A
```

Answer (score 1):

With table structure as:

```
create table Table1 (AllVisit int, UserDate datetime , UserID int)
insert into Table1 values (0,GETDATE()-1,1),(0,GETDATE()-1,2),(0,GETDATE()-1,3);
create table Table2 (ID int,UserID int,UserDate datetime)
insert into Table2 values (1,1,GETDATE()-1),(2,1,GETDATE()-1),(3,1,GETDATE()-1),(4,1,GETDATE()-1),(5,3,GETDATE()-1);
```

an `update` query like below will work:

```
update T1
SET T1.AllVisit = isnull(T3.idCount ,0)
FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY (select COUNT(T2.ID) AS idCount 
             from Table2 T2 
             WHERE T2.UserID = T1.UserID 
             And convert(date,T2.UserDate) = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) -- convert UserDate column to date type if it's a datetime
             group by T2.UserID)T3
WHERE convert(date,T1.UserDate) = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
```